# Getting row count on a Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

I've got a Kend UI grid inside a second tab of kedno tabstrip and I need to get number of rows in it. For this purposes I use

```
/**
 * Getting number of rows in grid by it's ID
 * @param {string} gridId ID of the Grid
 * @returns {number} number of rows
 */
function getGridRowsCountById(gridId) {
    var grid = $("#" + gridId).data("kendoGrid");

    console.log(grid);

    grid.dataSource.read();  

    return grid.dataSource.total();    
}
```

According to console log of gird object I've got nested dataSource object and _total property with number of rows value in it but total() always returns 0

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: I've move logic of counting number of rows to dataBound event of the grid and now it's working just fine

Comment: That because your grid probably retrieves the data in an async request, and you were calling the function before the data request ends.

Comment: Thanks a lot for advice!

Answer (score 4):

Try this function instead:

```
function getGridRowsCountById(gridId) {
    return $("#" + gridId).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length;
}
```

Avoid using properties started as underline, it is propably used for another purposes.